# poblem in python while combining 2 text file and summarizing them into a new text file

Tags: python

I have 2 text file like the following examples. I name one of them `first`(`comma separated`) and the other one `second`(`tab separated`).

`first`:

```
chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2
chr1,5310000,5960000,2,1,5,4
chr1,1580000,1180000,4,1,5,3
chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4
chr1,7680000,8300000,3,1,1,2
chr1,109220000,110070000,4,2,3,3
chr1,11060000,12070000,6,2,7,4
```

`second`:

```
AKAP8L  chr19   107180100   107650000   transcript
AKAP8L  chr19   15514130    15529799    transcript
AKIRIN2 chr6    88384790    88411927    transcript
AKIRIN2 chr6    88410228    88411243    transcript
AKT3    chr1    105002000   105010000   transcript
AKT3    chr1    243663021   244006886   transcript
AKT3    chr1    243665065   244013430   transcript
```

in the first file columns `2` and `3` are start and end. in the second file column `3` and `4` are start and end respectively. I want to make a new text file from both first and second files. 
in the new file I want to count the number of lines in the `file second` which match to every line in the `file first` based on the following criteria (3 columns):

```
1- the 1st column in file first is equal to 2nd column in file second.
2- the 3rd column in the file second is greater than the the 2nd column in the file first and also smaller than the 3rd column in the file first.
3- the 4th column in the file second should be also greater than the the 2nd column in the file first and also smaller than the 3rd column in the file first.
```

in act the output looks like the expected output. the first 7 columns are directly from the `file first` but the 9th column is the number of lines in the `file second` that match every single line in the `file first` (based on 3 mentioned above criteria). and the `8th column` would be "the first column of the line from the `file second` that matches to specific line of file first"

`expected output`:

```
chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4,AKAP8L, 1
chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2, AKT3, 1
```

I am trying to do that in python and wrote this code but it does not return what I am looking for.

```
first = open('first.csv', 'rb')
second = open('second.txt', 'rb')
first_file = []
for line in first:
    first_file.append(line.split(','))

second_file = []
for line2 in second:
    second_file.append(line.split())

count=0
final = []
for i in range(len(first_file)):
    for j in range(len(second_file)):
        first_row = first_file[i]
        second_row = second_file[j]
        first_col = first_row.split()
        second_col = second_row.split()
        if first_col[0] == second_col[1] and first_col[1] < second_col[2] < first_col[2] and first_col[1] < second_col[3] < first_col[2]
            count+=1
            final.append(first_col[i]+second_col[0]+count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you don't have column names this looks really robust, but it works and uses `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

first = 'first.csv'
second = 'second.txt'

df1 = pd.read_csv(first, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(second, sep='\s+', header=None)

merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=[0], right_on=[1], suffixes=('first', 'second'))
a, b, c, d = merged['2second'], merged['1first'], merged['2first'], merged['3second']

cleaned = merged[(c>a)&(a>b)&(c>d)&(d>b)]

counted = cleaned.groupby(['0first', '1first', '2first', '3first', '4first', 5, 6, '0second'])['4second'].count().reset_index()

counted.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

This produces the `result.csv` with following content:

```
chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2,AKT3,1
chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4,AKAP8L,1
```

Answer (score 0):

In you same setting if you do as below it will work.

```
first = open('first.csv', 'r')
second = open('second.txt', 'r')
first_file = []
for line in first:
    first_file.append(line.strip())
second_file = []
for line2 in second:
    second_file.append(line2)
count=0
final = []
for i in range(len(first_file)):
    for j in range(len(second_file)):
        first_row = first_file[i]
        second_row = second_file[j]
        first_col = first_row.split(',')
        second_col = second_row.split()
        if (first_col[0] == second_col[1]) and (first_col[1] < second_col[2] < first_col[2]) and (first_col[1] < second_col[3] < first_col[2]):
            count = count + 1
            final.append(first_row +','+second_col[0]+',' + str(count))
print(final)
```

This will generate the same result what you want.

```
['chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2,AKT3,1', 'chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4,AKAP8L,2']
```